# how to display values from database using between query in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

This is my table wys_attendence:

```
id   studid  adate  amonth  ayear  acls_id  attendence      
1    28      29     07      2015   10       1     
2    31      29     07      2015   10       0  
4    32      29     07      2015   10       1   
5    28      30     07      2015   10       0 
6    31      30     07      2015   10       1   
7    32      30     07      2015   10       1   
9    28      31     07      2015   10       1   
10   31      31     07      2015   10       1   
11   32      31     07      2015   10       1   
13   28      01     08      2015   10       1   
14   31      01     08      2015   10       0   
15   32      01     08      2015   10       1   
17   28      02     08      2015   10       0   
18   31      02     08      2015   10       1   
19   32      02     08      2015   10       1   
21   28      03     08      2015   10       1   
22   31      03     08      2015   10       1   
23   32      03     08      2015   10       0   
24   28      04     08      2015   10       1   
25   31      04     08      2015   10       1   
26   32      04     08      2015   10       0
```

I want to check if values between the t_adates is in the table, and to display values from between the t_adates

if I am select `29/07/2015 to 03/08/0215`.

The output I get is incorrect. This is what I get:

```
 studid  
  28     
  31     
  32
```

not display dates and corresponding values

But I want it like this:

```
studid  29  30 31 01 02  03
  28     1   0  1  1  0   1
  31     0   1  1  0  1   1
  32     1   1  1  1  1   0
```

my controller code is here

```
       `$startdate_exploded = explode("/",Input::get('curdate'));          
        $enddate_exploded = explode("/",Input::get('enddate'));              
        $curdate =  Input::get('curdate');
        $enddate =  Input::get('enddate');
        $teacher = WysTeacher::all();
        $attendance = DB::table('wys_teacherattendances')
                     ->whereBetween('t_adate', array($startdate_exploded[0], $enddate_exploded[0]))
                    ->whereBetween('t_amonth', array($startdate_exploded[1], $enddate_exploded[1]))
                    ->whereBetween('t_ayear', array($startdate_exploded[2], $enddate_exploded[2]))
                    ->groupBy('t_adate')
                    ->get();
       $teacher_daysattend=WysTeacherattendance::whereBetween('t_adate', array($startdate_exploded[0], $enddate_exploded[0]))
                    ->whereBetween('t_amonth', array($startdate_exploded[1], $enddate_exploded[1]))
                    ->whereBetween('t_ayear', array($startdate_exploded[2], $enddate_exploded[2]))  
                    ->get();`
```

my **view.blade.php** code is here
                       `<table class="table table-hover" id="datatable">
                         @foreach($attendance as $attendances)
                      <th>{{$attendances->t_adate}}</th>
                       @endforeach
                      </tr>
                      @foreach($teacher as $teachers)
                      <tr>

                      <td>{{$teachers->tname}}</td>
                      @foreach($teacher_daysattend as $teacher_daysattends)
                      @if($teachers->user_id == $teacher_daysattends->t_auserid) 
                      @if($teacher_daysattends->t_attendance == 1 )
                      <td><font color="green">1</font></td>
                      @elseif($teacher_daysattends->t_attendance == 0)
                      <td><font color="red">0</font></td>

                      @endif
                      @endif
                      @endforeach
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </table>`

How can I modify my query to achieve the above result as well as check all day ,month ad year.if iam select dates (29/07/2015 to 03/08/2015 ) are in the database or not if in database then day display only once and display all details from database?

Comment: From what I can see your first between is going between 29 and 03 which doesn't quite make sense in logic. Why don't you just make one column for dates and do it that way?

Comment: is its not possible?? i want  display 29/07/2015 to 03/08/2015 days values only.. what is the  code for display value of this 29/07/2015 to 03/08/2015.